# how to generate a random token with md5

Tags: go

I'm trying to generate a random token that I can use while implementing reset password functionality. This (http://play.golang.org/p/mmAzXLIZML) is the dazzling and non-functional :( code that I came up with for a first try. It doesn't work as I'd hope because it produces the same token over and over again (which I assume is a function of the time not changing). How do I generate a random token with md5 that will change every time?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"
import "time"
import "crypto/md5"
import "io"


func main() {


    time := strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
    fmt.Println(time)
    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, time)
    fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/mmAzXLIZML

Comment: Can you use a random number? Such as [here](https://gobyexample.com/random-numbers)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It generates the same result each time only because it's in the playground, where time is frozen and pages are cached.

This isn't a great idea though, since a reset password could be guessed based on the time the request was made.

Why does it have to be an md5? Here's a random token generator:

http://play.golang.org/p/3weHBU6YZr

```
func randToken() string {
    b := make([]byte, 8)
    rand.Read(b)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
}
```

Comment: I was in the process of writing this, but you were faster

Comment: This is easier. thanks.  The reset password could only be guessed if they knew that time was being used to generate the token, and then also guessed the time.

Comment: @Leahcim: *never* count on an obscure process being secure simply because it's not known. Systems similar to what you tried are broken all the time.

Comment: +1 for Jim's response. There's almost no need to use MD5 (or any hashing algorithm here). Alternatively, you could also `base64.URLEncoding` the output if you want to make a little shorter, although hex is totally fine for a password reset system. I would probably increase the number of random bytes to at least ~16 though - and make sure to aggressively expire (<= 4 hours?) the tokens. Redis would be good for this - generate, add to Redis with expiry, and then check Redis when verifying the token.

Comment: Note that in the go playground, it doesn't generate a random token.

Comment: Is this secure enough to implement on a low traffic site?

Comment: @majidarif: generating a random string from `crypto/rand` is safe, but whether it's "secure" is completely up to how you handle the security on your site.

Comment: Note that the `rand.Read()` used should be from `crypto/rand`, NOT `math/rand`.

Comment: @QuentinSkousen: the example in the answer uses `crypto/rand`, and the comment above your says `crypto/rand`, so I'm not sure what you're commenting on.

Comment: @JimB, it has it in the playground example but not the shown code, and it's an easy mistake to make for someone who doesn't know the difference. Thanks for the answer, I have used it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

uuid is annother chooice. see

```
go get  "code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid"
```

and the func **uuid.New()** is what you wanted.

Comment: The UUIDs as not designed with security in mind (i.e they are predictable)